# Apache tomcat 9.1.10 shows Active (exited) in Ubuntu 18.0.4, but apache tomcat web page is loading

Tags: tomcat

Apache tomcat 9.1.10 shows Active (exited) in Ubuntu 18.0.4, but apache tomcat web page is loading. Below is the messge that shows in my terminal

tomcat.service - LSB: Start and stop Apache Tomcat
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/tomcat; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Mon 2018-10-08 11:41:41 IST; 23h ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 12330 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/tomcat stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS
  Process: 12351 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/tomcat start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS
    Tasks: 0
   Memory: 0B
      CPU: 0